Simple raycast hit object implementation intro custom lib based on webgpu tech
This raycast funcs originally writen for glmatrix because i use
wgpu-matrix ^2.5.1 i made args modification. Ussually for glmatrix vec3 mat4 operation have  destination out on begin in wgpu-matrix it is a last arg in call.
Source code live example

Raycast complite implemention
/**
 * @author Nikola Lukic
 * @email zlatnaspirala@gmail.com
 * @site https://maximumroulette.com
 * @Licence GPL v3
 * Inspired with original code from:
 * https://github.com/Necolo/raycaster
 * 
 * @Note matrix-engine-wgpu adaptation test
 * WIP
 * 
 * default for now:
 * app.cameras['WASD']
 */

import {mat4, vec3, vec4} from "wgpu-matrix";

let rayHitEvent;

export let touchCoordinate = {
    enabled: false,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    stopOnFirstDetectedHit: false
};

/**
 * @description 
 * Ray triangle intersection algorithm.
 * @param rayOrigin ray origin point
 * @param rayVector ray direction
 * @param triangle three points of triangle, should be ccw order
 * @param out the intersection point
 * @return intersects or not
 * Uses Möller–Trumbore intersection algorithm
 */
export function rayIntersectsTriangle(
    rayOrigin, // vec3,
    rayVector, // vec3,
    triangle,  // vec3[],
    out,       // vec3,
    objPos) {
    if(app.cameras.WASD.position_[2] < objPos.Z) {
        rayOrigin[2] = app.cameras.WASD.position_[2] - parseFloat(objPos.Z);
    } else {
        rayOrigin[2] = app.cameras.WASD.position_[2] + -parseFloat(objPos.Z);
    }

    rayOrigin[0] = app.cameras.WASD.position_[0];
    rayOrigin[1] = app.cameras.WASD.position_[1];

    // const EPSILON = 0.0000001;
    const EPSILON = 0.000001;
    const [v0, v1, v2] = triangle;
    const edge1 = vec3.create();
    const edge2 = vec3.create();
    const h = vec3.create();

    // vec3.sub(edge1, v1, v0);
    // vec3.sub(edge2, v2, v0);
    vec3.sub(v1, v0, edge1)
    vec3.sub(v2, v0, edge2)

    if(rayVector[0] > 0) {
        // console.log('ray vector ', rayVector)
    }

    /**
     * (static) cross(out, a, b) → {vec3}
        Computes the cross product of two vec3's
        Parameters:
        Name    Type    Description
        out vec3    the receiving vector
        a   ReadonlyVec3    the first operand
        b   ReadonlyVec3    the second operand
     */
    // vec3.cross(h, rayVector, edge2);
    vec3.cross(rayVector, edge2, h);

    const a = vec3.dot(edge1, h);

    if(a > -EPSILON && a < EPSILON) {
        return false;
    }

    const s = vec3.create();
    // glmatrix  out , v , v 
    // ori gmatrix   vec3.sub(s, rayOrigin, v0);
    vec3.sub(rayOrigin, v0, s);
    const u = vec3.dot(s, h);
    // const uTest = vec3.dot(h, s);
    // console.log('TEST u = ', u , '  uTest , ', uTest)

    if(u < 0 || u > a) {return false}

    const q = vec3.create();

    // ori vec3.cross(q, s, edge1);
    vec3.cross(s, edge1, q);

    const v = vec3.dot(rayVector, q);

    if(v < 0 || u + v > a) {
        return false
    }

    const t = vec3.dot(edge2, q) / a;
    if(t > EPSILON) {
        if(out) {
            // ori vec3.add(out, rayOrigin, [rayVector[0] * t, rayVector[1] * t, rayVector[2] * t]);
            vec3.add(rayOrigin, [rayVector[0] * t, rayVector[1] * t, rayVector[2] * t], out);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * @description
 * Unproject a 2D point into a 3D world.
 * @param screenCoord [screenX, screenY]
 * @param viewport [left, top, width, height]
 * @param invProjection invert projection matrix
 * @param invView invert view matrix
 * @return 3D point position
 */
export function unproject(
    screenCoord,   // [number, number]
    viewport,      // [number, number, number, number]
    invProjection, // mat4
    invView) {
    // return vec3
    const [left, top, width, height] = viewport;
    const [x, y] = screenCoord;
    // console.log("test out x=", x)
    // console.log("test out y=", y)
    const out = vec4.fromValues((2 * x) / width - 1 - left, (2 * (height - y - 1)) / height - 1, 1, 1);
    // console.log("1 out =", out)

    // ori glmatrix
    //   vec4.transformMat4(out, out, invProjection);
    vec4.transformMat4(out, invProjection, out);

    // console.log("2 out =", out)
    out[3] = 0;
    vec4.transformMat4(out, invView, out);
    // console.log("3 out x=", out[1], ' y=', out[2])
    return vec3.normalize(out, vec3.create());
}

/**
 * @description 
 * Fix local rotation raycast bug test.
 */
export function rotate2dPlot(cx, cy, x, y, angle) {
    var radians = (Math.PI / 180) * -angle,
        cos = Math.cos(radians),
        sin = Math.sin(radians),
        nx = cos * (x - cx) + sin * (y - cy) + cx,
        ny = cos * (y - cy) - sin * (x - cx) + cy;
    return [nx, ny];
}

export function checkingProcedure(ev, customArg) {
    let {clientX, clientY, screenX, screenY} = ev;

    if(typeof customArg !== 'undefined') {
        clientX = customArg.clientX;
        clientY = customArg.clientY;
    }

    touchCoordinate.x = clientX;
    touchCoordinate.y = clientY;
    if(typeof ev.target.width != 'undefined') touchCoordinate.w = ev.target.width;
    if(typeof ev.target.height != 'undefined') touchCoordinate.h = ev.target.height;
    touchCoordinate.enabled = true;
}

export function checkingRay(object) {
    try {
        if(object.raycast.enabled == false || touchCoordinate.enabled == false) return;
        touchCoordinate.enabled = false;
        // modelViewProjectionMatrix
        // let mvMatrix = [...object.modelViewProjectionMatrix];
        let ray;
        let outp = mat4.create();
        let outv = mat4.create();
        let myRayOrigin = vec3.fromValues(app.cameras.WASD.position_[0], app.cameras.WASD.position_[1], app.cameras.WASD.position_[2]);

        if(app.cameras.WASD.position_[2] < object.position.z) {
            myRayOrigin = vec3.fromValues(app.cameras.WASD.position_[0], app.cameras.WASD.position_[1], -app.cameras.WASD.position_[2]);
        }

        // NOT WORK TEST 1
        // let projectionMatrix = new Float32Array([...object.projectionMatrix])
        // let modelViewProjectionMatrix = new Float32Array([...object.modelViewProjectionMatrix])

        // // TEST 2
        // let projectionMatrix = new Float32Array([...object.modelViewProjectionMatrix])
        // let modelViewProjectionMatrix = new Float32Array([...object.viewMatrix])

        let projectionMatrix = new Float32Array([...object.projectionMatrix])
        let modelViewProjectionMatrix = new Float32Array([...object.viewMatrix])
        // modelViewProjectionMatrix   viewMatrix

        // ori world.pMatrix ?!
        // object.projectionMatrix
        var TEST1 = mat4.inverse(modelViewProjectionMatrix);
        var TEST2 = mat4.inverse(projectionMatrix);
        
       // console.log("test ############ ====>  ", touchCoordinate.w)
        // ray = unproject([touchCoordinate.x, touchCoordinate.y], [0, 0, touchCoordinate.w, touchCoordinate.h], mat4.invert(outp, projectionMatrix), mat4.invert(outv, modelViewProjectionMatrix));
        ray = unproject([touchCoordinate.x, touchCoordinate.y], [0, 0, touchCoordinate.w, touchCoordinate.h], TEST2, TEST1);

        // console.log("ray ====>  ", ray)

        if(ray[0] > 0) {
            // console.log('ray >', ray)
        }
        // return;
        const intersectionPoint = vec3.create();
        object.raycastFace = [];

        for(var f = 0;f < object.mesh.indices.length;f = f + 3) {
            var a = object.mesh.indices[f];
            var b = object.mesh.indices[f + 1];
            var c = object.mesh.indices[f + 2];
            let triangle = null;
            const triangleInZero = [
                [object.mesh.vertices[0 + a * 3], object.mesh.vertices[1 + a * 3], object.mesh.vertices[2 + a * 3]],
                [object.mesh.vertices[0 + b * 3], object.mesh.vertices[1 + b * 3], object.mesh.vertices[2 + b * 3]],
                [object.mesh.vertices[0 + c * 3], object.mesh.vertices[1 + c * 3], object.mesh.vertices[2 + c * 3]]
            ];


            triangle = [
                [triangleInZero[0][0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], triangleInZero[0][1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], triangleInZero[0][2]+ object.position.worldLocation[2]],
                [triangleInZero[1][0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], triangleInZero[1][1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], triangleInZero[1][2]+ object.position.worldLocation[2]],
                [triangleInZero[2][0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], triangleInZero[2][1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], triangleInZero[2][2]+ object.position.worldLocation[2]]
            ];

            var rez0, rez1, rez2;

            if(object.rotation.toDegreeX() != 0) {
                rez0 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[0][1], triangleInZero[0][2], object.rotation.toDegreeX());
                rez1 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[1][1], triangleInZero[1][2], object.rotation.toDegreeX());
                rez2 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[2][1], triangleInZero[2][2], object.rotation.toDegreeX());
                triangle = [
                    [triangleInZero[0][0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], rez0[0] + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez0[1]],
                    [triangleInZero[1][0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], rez1[0] + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez1[1]],
                    [triangleInZero[2][0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], rez2[0] + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez2[1]]
                ];
            }
            // y z changed - rez0[1] is z
            if(object.rotation.toDegreeY() != 0) {
                if(object.rotation.toDegreeX() != 0) {
                    // Y i Z
                    // get y
                    rez0 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[0][1], triangleInZero[0][2], object.rotation.toDegreeX() - 90);
                    rez1 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[1][1], triangleInZero[1][2], object.rotation.toDegreeX() - 90);
                    rez2 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[2][1], triangleInZero[2][2], object.rotation.toDegreeX() - 90);
                    const detY0 = rez0[0];
                    const detY1 = rez1[0];
                    const detY2 = rez2[0];

                    const detZ0 = rez0[1];
                    const detZ1 = rez1[1];
                    const detZ2 = rez2[1];

                    //                          X INITIAL             Z
                    rez0 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[0][0], detZ0, object.rotation.toDegreeY() - 90);
                    rez1 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[1][0], detZ1, object.rotation.toDegreeY() - 90);
                    rez2 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[2][0], detZ2, object.rotation.toDegreeY() - 90);

                    const detZ00 = rez0[1];
                    const detZ11 = rez1[1];
                    const detZ22 = rez2[1];

                    rez0 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, rez0[0], detY0, object.rotation.toDegreeZ() - 90);
                    rez1 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, rez1[0], detY1, object.rotation.toDegreeZ() - 90);
                    rez2 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, rez2[0], detY2, object.rotation.toDegreeZ() - 90);

                    triangle = [
                        [rez0[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], rez0[1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], detZ00],
                        [rez1[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], rez1[1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], detZ11],
                        [rez2[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], rez2[1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], detZ22]
                    ];
                } else if(object.rotation.rz == 0) {
                    rez0 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[0][0], triangleInZero[0][2], -object.rotation.toDegreeY());
                    rez1 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[1][0], triangleInZero[1][2], -object.rotation.toDegreeY());
                    rez2 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[2][0], triangleInZero[2][2], -object.rotation.toDegreeY());

                    triangle = [
                        [rez0[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], triangleInZero[0][1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez0[1]],
                        [rez1[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], triangleInZero[1][1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez1[1]],
                        [rez2[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], triangleInZero[2][1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], rez2[1]]
                    ];
                }
            }

            if(object.rotation.toDegreeZ() != 0) {
                if(object.rotation.toDegreeY() != 0) {
                    if(object.rotation.toDegreeX() == 180) {
                        rez0 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[0][0], triangleInZero[0][2], object.rotation.toDegreeY());
                        rez1 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[1][0], triangleInZero[1][2], object.rotation.toDegreeY());
                        rez2 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[2][0], triangleInZero[2][2], object.rotation.toDegreeY());

                        let detZ00 = rez0[1];
                        let detZ11 = rez1[1];
                        let detZ22 = rez2[1];

                        rez0 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, rez0[0], triangleInZero[0][1], object.rotation.toDegreeZ());
                        rez1 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, rez1[0], triangleInZero[1][1], object.rotation.toDegreeZ());
                        rez2 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, rez2[0], triangleInZero[2][1], object.rotation.toDegreeZ());

                        const detZ0 = rez0[1];
                        const detZ1 = rez1[1];
                        const detZ2 = rez2[1];
                        // rez0 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0,rez0[0], detZ00, object.rotation.rx - 180);
                        // rez1 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0,rez0[0], detZ11, object.rotation.rx - 180);
                        // rez2 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, rez0[0], detZ22, object.rotation.rx - 180);
                        // detZ00 = rez0[1];
                        // detZ11 = rez1[1];
                        // detZ22 = rez2[1];
                        triangle = [
                            [rez0[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], detZ0 + object.position.worldLocation[1], detZ00],
                            [rez1[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], detZ1 + object.position.worldLocation[1], detZ11],
                            [rez2[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], detZ2 + object.position.worldLocation[1], detZ22]
                        ];
                    } else {
                        // console.info(`unhandled ray cast triangle = ${triangle}`);
                    }
                } else {
                    if(object.rotation.toDegreeX() == 0) {
                        rez0 = rotate2dPlot(0, +0, triangleInZero[0][0], triangleInZero[0][1], object.rotation.toDegreeZ());
                        rez1 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[1][0], triangleInZero[1][1], object.rotation.toDegreeZ());
                        rez2 = rotate2dPlot(0, 0, triangleInZero[2][0], triangleInZero[2][1], object.rotation.toDegreeZ());
                        triangle = [
                            [rez0[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], rez0[1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], triangleInZero[0][2]],
                            [rez1[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], rez1[1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], triangleInZero[1][2]],
                            [rez2[0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], rez2[1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], triangleInZero[2][2]]
                        ];
                    } else {
                        // var test;
                        // console.info('must be handled rz vs rx');
                    }
                }
            }

            // no rot
            if(object.rotation.toDegreeX() == 0 && object.rotation.toDegreeY() == 0 && object.rotation.toDegreeZ() == 0) {
                triangle = [
                    [triangleInZero[0][0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], triangleInZero[0][1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], triangleInZero[0][2]],
                    [triangleInZero[1][0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], triangleInZero[1][1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], triangleInZero[1][2]],
                    [triangleInZero[2][0] + object.position.worldLocation[0], triangleInZero[2][1] + object.position.worldLocation[1], triangleInZero[2][2]]
                ];
            }

            object.raycastFace.push(triangle);

            if(rayIntersectsTriangle(myRayOrigin, ray, triangle, intersectionPoint, object.position)) {
                rayHitEvent = new CustomEvent('ray.hit.event', {
                    detail: {
                        touchCoordinate: {x: touchCoordinate.x, y: touchCoordinate.y},
                        hitObject: object,
                        intersectionPoint: intersectionPoint,
                        ray: ray,
                        rayOrigin: myRayOrigin
                    }
                });
                dispatchEvent(rayHitEvent);
                if(touchCoordinate.enabled == true && touchCoordinate.stopOnFirstDetectedHit == true) {
                    touchCoordinate.enabled = false;
                }
                // console.info('raycast hits for Object: ' + object.name + '  -> face[/3]  : ' + f + ' -> intersectionPoint: ' + intersectionPoint);
            }
        }

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

Maybe i need to involve angle also i not sure for this part.
It is axis angle presentation of rotation comes from ammojs (quaternion).
Rotator
    toDegreeX() {
        return radToDeg(this.axis.x)
    }

    toDegreeY() {
        return radToDeg(this.axis.y)
    }

    toDegreeZ() {
        return radToDeg(this.axis.z)
    }

My camera have affect on hit area also is bad...
